# Pytorch - Trick AutoGrad into thinking another output is the final outcome

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

#### The scenario:

- I have a simple torch CNN network that predicts if a given image input is a dog or a cat.
- After getting the output of the neural network, I need to apply a modifier of X to each prediction. For example, if the neural network return [0.6, 0.4], and I want to apply a modifier of [0.05, -0.03], I need the result to be [0.65, 0.37].

#### The desired result:

- I would like AutoGrad to think the final output is [0.65, 0.37]. That is, AutoGrad shouldn't consider the modifier addition at all. In fact, It needs to be tricked into thinking the last operation result is [0.65, 0.37] instead of [0.6, 0.4], and apply the backpropagation with that in mind.

#### Here's what I need to know:

- How am I suppose to do this? I know Torch records every single operation and compute a dynamic graph accordingly. I don't want this operation to be recorded at all, and I can't use the `torch.no_grad()` wrapper, because I need to be able to do the backpropagation after.

---

#### Edit 1

@trsvchn Here's what happen when I do your method. Is this expected? Will autograd use the "T" value instead of the "data" value when doing the backpropagation?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `torch.no_grad` context manager to deactivate `autograd`, for example this operation is not going to be recorded, but you should use in-place operation, otherwise you will add another tensor without `grad_fn` and break the graph. In your case:

```py
out = model(inputs)  # [0.6, 0.4]

with torch.no_grad():
    out.add_(torch.tensor([0.05, -0.03]))  # inplace add_ op
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It does seem the AutoGrad is intact after doing this. The "T" attribute does seem to change. However, the "data" attribute doesn't, and when I call `out.cpu().detach().numpy()` it returns the tensor data before applying the `add_` method. Please check my original question edit.

Answer (score 0):

This should be quite simple:
Any mathematical operation you put into your `forward` function normally gets included into the backpropagation because its added to the computational graph.
SO from my understanding you could do the following:

```py
def forward(self, x):
    x = self.layer1(x)
    x = self.layerN(x)

    x = x + torch.tensor([0.5, -0.3]).cuda() #or .cpu()
```

You can do any mathematical operation you want in forward (as long as it includes torch tensors) and it will be included in the backpropagation.

Comment: Before I asked this question, I tried this and it didn't work. Thank you for your answer, though!